# PHP: Не работает mail()

Tags: php, html, email, функции

Добрый вечер.
Что-то не работает функция mail(), хотя на хостинге есть возможность отправлять почту (тестил более примитивным).

Форма:

```
<form class="mg-t-sm" role="form" method="post" action="php/rsvp.php" id="rsvpForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="yourName">Ваше полное имя</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="yourName" type="text" id="yourName" placeholder="Ваше полное имя" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="yourEmail">Ваш email адрес</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="yourMail" type="email" id="yourEmail" placeholder="Ваш email адрес" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="yourGuests">Количество гостей</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="yourGuests" type="text" id="yourGuests" placeholder="Количество гостей" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="yourMessage">Ваши пожелания молодоженам</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="yourReal" type="hidden" id="yourReal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="yourMessage" id="yourMessage" placeholder="Ваши пожелания молодоженам" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-wrap">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </div>
    <div id="successMsg" class="hidden">
        <br>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>Thanks, your message has been sent!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP-код:

```
<?php 

$to      = "adobe-master@ukr.net";         // add your email address
$subject = "RSVP form submission";     // the subject of emails

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $name    = check_input($_POST['name']);
    $email   = check_input($_POST['email']);
    $guests   = check_input($_POST['guests']);
    $message = check_input($_POST['message']);
    $human   = check_input($_POST['human']);

    if (empty($human)) {
        $headers  = "From: " . $to . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

        $body = "<html><body>";
        $body .= "<h1>" . $subject . "</h1>";
        $body .= "<p><strong>Name: </strong>" . $name . "</p>";
        $body .= "<p><strong>E-mail: </strong>" . $email . "</p>";
        $body .= "<p><strong>Guests: </strong>" . $guests . "</p>";        
        $body .= "<p>" . strip_tags($message) . "</p>";
        $body .= "</body></html>";

        if (!empty($to) && !empty($subject) && !empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($guests) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($message)) {
            mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
            echo("success");
        }
    } else { echo("success"); }
}

function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Папки спам проверяли? приходит ли завёрнутое письмо?

Comment: Используйте PHPMailer или email-шлюзы, например Mailgun.